# Compare of 2 arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to compare the 2 arrays below, using array_diff but keep receiving error
`Exception: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

As I can see the arrays have the same columns, albeit in different order.

What I am hoping to achieve is getting the difference in the arrays, namely the objects with year 5 associated with them.

**Array 1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [resources_id] => 29527
            [pages_sections_id] => 1319
            [year] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [resources_id] => 29527
            [pages_sections_id] => 1298
            [year] => 3
        )

)
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pages_sections_id] => 1319
            [resources_id] => 29527
            [year] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pages_sections_id] => 1298
            [resources_id] => 29527
            [year] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pages_sections_id] => 1377
            [resources_id] => 29527
            [year] => 5
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pages_sections_id] => 1380
            [resources_id] => 29527
            [year] => 5
        )

)
```

I am using array_diff `array_diff($array1, $array2)`

Comment: This is an array of objects, so it's not comparable with array_diff.

How are these arrays created? Is it decoded JSON?

Comment: One set is passed through a form submission, and the other is from a query

Comment: Forms do not generally submit as objects, you must be doing something else between them.